# Storyboard in Corona

Tags: lua, storyboard, coronasdk

I'm having trouble with Storyboard module. After I move to another room module and come back to this module. the view in kitchenView module is not created again. Isn't the code in enterScene executed again?

```
function scene:enterScene( event )
 local group = self.view

 KitchenModel = require("kitchenModel")
 kitchenModel = KitchenModel:new()
 kitchenModel:init()

 KitchenView = require("kitchenView")
 kitchenView=KitchenView:new()
 kitchenView:init()
 group:insert(kitchenView.view)

 KitchenController= require("kitchenController")
 kitchenController =KitchenController:new()
 kitchenController:init(kitchenModel, kitchenView)
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After removing Runtime listener in kitchenController module, it worked. I guess adding new runtime listeners without removing old ones corrupts the code.